# How to deploy fuelphp website to server

Tags: apache, fuelphp

I'm new to fuelPHP, I developed a simple application and when I uploaded the files to my web server I got those errors :

```
Notice: Use of undefined constant __DIR__ - assumed '__DIR__' in /home1/tdfdf/public_html/site/site/public/index.php on line 22

Fatal error: require() [function.require]: Failed opening required '/bootstrap.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/lib/php:/usr/share/pear') in /home1/tdfdf/public_html/site/site/public/index.php on line 44
```

I probably miss some configurations here. I also want to remove this "/public" from the url

Can any one help ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. The **DIR** is not defined for older versions of PHP . I changed my server settings to run on  PHP 5.3 and it worked like magic.

Thanks.